# drop shadow style for IE11

Tags: css

I have created a web-page and applied drop shadow effect by using filter as follow:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=0, Color='gray', Positive='true');
```

This works fine for IE 8 and 9, but on IE 11 doesn't work. How can the style be applied in modern browsers?

Comment: DX filter is no longer supported since IE10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround as there is no real solution from Microsoft.

If you want to add a shadow to a basic rectangular block element, use box-shadow.
However, you probably have a more complex element - a triangle for example.

In that case you could fake the effect by using a **absolute pseudo or child element**. Depending on the style you need, use a transformed box-shadow, border or duplicate the content from the main element and scale it underneath, blur it using SVG...

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IE 10 and newer support [text-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow) and [box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow), so you no longer need to apply any special rules for them.

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 gray
```

or

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 gray
```

Comment: i want it for border shadow purpose

Comment: then use `box-shadow`!

Answer (score -2):

You are using a proprietary filter of Microsoft. In newer versions use the standard CSS

```
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px #f00;
```

Its values are Xaxis Yaxis blur color

Comment: i want it for border shadow purpose

Comment: yeah but i have triangle shape div and its border are used for that shape i want shadow in triangle shape, can this be possible with box-shadow property

Comment: To imitate your code you must to put the blur to zero `box-shadow : 1px 1px 0 grey`

Comment: box-shadow and drop-shadow are not the same thing for images with transparency. Why is this accepted?

Comment: Box shadow is the css property to make a drop shadow. What's the problem?

Comment: Works if you've only got a box - but i'm using a "before:" element with an arrow protruding from the box - and this element does not have the drop shadow. Bloody IE.